# Dealing with Azure Storage Queue list without any QueuMessage in ADF ForEach

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-storage-queues, dynamic-expression

I am using WebActivity to get QueueMessage from Azure Blob Storage and pass the output to ForEeach to use each QueueMessage in subsequent pipeline process.The pipeline is on schedule run and this is the Dynamic Expression I use in ForEach Items:

```
@json(xml(activity('get_queue_message').output.Response)).QueueMessagesList.QueueMessage
```

It works fine when there are MessageText in the queue. But once the queue is cleared and the webactivity returns empty QueueMessageList as per below, the ForEach will start to fail

```
{
 "Response": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><QueueMessagesList />",
 "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
     "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
     "x-ms-request-id": "requestid",
     "x-ms-version": "2020-04-08",
     "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
     "Date": "Tue, 13 Jun 2023 07:53:30 GMT",
     "Server": "Windows-Azure-Queue/1.0;Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
     "Content-Type": "application/xml"
 },
 "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (Southeast Asia)",
 "executionDuration": 0,
 "durationInQueue": {
     "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
 },
 "billingReference": {
     "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
     "billableDuration": [
         {
             "meterType": "AzureIR",
             "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
             "unit": "Hours"
         }
     ]
 }
}
```

ForEach Failure as follows:

> The expression 'length(json(xml(activity('get_queue_message').output.Response)).QueueMessagesList.QueueMessage)' cannot be evaluated because property 'QueueMessage' cannot be selected.

What is the correct way to check for the QueueMessageList before running ForEach. If the queue is empty, i would like to stop the ForEach without triggering any error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the `QueueMessagesList` is empty before running the `ForEach` activity, you can use the `if` function to conditionally execute the `ForEach` activity only if the `QueueMessagesList` is not empty.  Since the `ForEach` activity cannot be used directly inside an `If Condition` activity, you can design a two level pipeline by using the combination of `If Condition` and `Execute Pipeline` activities to achieve the requirement. In outer pipeline take the web activity and if activity. Inside if activity take the execute pipeline activity.

**Outer Pipeline:**
[image]

- Take the Web activity and then if condition activity. Give the expression as,

```
@contains(json(xml(activity('get_queue_message').output.Response)).QueueMessagesList,'QueueMessage')
```

This expression will return `true` if the `QueueMessagesList` property contains one or more `QueueMessage` elements, and `false` if the `QueueMessagesList` property is empty. that is, it does not contain any `QueueMessage` elements.

- You can also give the expression as

```
@not(empty(json(xml(activity('get_queue_message').output.Response)).QueueMessagesList))
```

This expression returns `true` if there are messages in the `QueueMessagesList` property, and `false` if there are no messages.

- In true section of If activity you can add execute pipeline activity and in false branch, leave it as empty (no activities inside it).

**Inner Pipeline:**

- In the execute pipeline activity, you can invoke the pipeline that contains web activity and for-each activity.

[image]

This way, you can execute the `ForEach` activity only if the `QueueMessagesList` is not empty.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I like this idea and attempted to do so. Strangely when there are Queues in the Azure Queue and I ran the outer pipeline which succesfully triggered the inner pipeline, the Execute Pipeline1 activity fail with this error: '
Operation on target ForEach1 failed: The expression 'length(json(xml(activity('get_queue_message').output.Response)).QueueMessagesList.QueueMessage)' cannot be evaluated because property 'QueueMessage' cannot be selected.' But when i run the inner pipeline directly, it ran succesfully. I wonder why..

Comment: Perhaps the input of web activity in outer and inner pipeline are different. Could you check that?

Comment: Also. Which expression did you choose in If condition? first or second?

Comment: Did you check the option `Wait on completion` in execute pipeline activity?

Comment: I have checked and confirmed the input of web activity in outer and inner pipeline are the same. I have also tried both expressions, they give same error if i put the ExecutePipeline within IfCondition. In other words when the Queue is not empty and IfCondition is met, the get_message_queue in the inner pipeline that is triggered by IfCondition somehow cannot fetch the QueueMessage and returns blank list. I added a 30 seconds Wait before ExecutePipeline within the If Condition and it now works. I suspect I cannot call the QueueMessage API within too close timespan, is it right?